# How to install touchegg?

Tags: installation, touchegg

I'm trying to install touchegg but for some reason it doesn't work.

For now all I tried:

1. `sudo apt-get install touchegg`
2. `edit ~/.config/touchegg/touchegg.conf` (What is the appropriate format? Plain text or XML?)

How do i make it work?

Comment: please provide some more information on the issue (e.g. the errors thrown).

Answer (score 2):

Based on Software Centre user reviews (Ie. this app segfaults) and the Touchegg [Downloads page](http://code.google.com/p/touchegg/wiki/Downloads?tm=2), you can only apt-get this app with Ubuntu 11.10 and below. Touchegg does not play nice with Unity.

For 12.10, download and compile the source code following [these instructions](http://code.google.com/p/touchegg/wiki/CompileSourceCode). See the aforementioned [Downloads page](http://code.google.com/p/touchegg/wiki/Downloads?tm=2) and this [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/touchegg/issues/detail?id=174) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

[Touchegg](https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg) is maintained and functionning.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:touchegg/stable
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install touchegg
```

I just installed it and it seems like a great way to have control over your trackpad including 3 fingers, 4 fingers gestures.